# how to create buttons in gridview?

Tags: android, xml, button, gridview

i want to create buttons in grid view (3-buttons per row)

```
XMLcode:

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="3"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="Button" />

</GridLayout>
```

i want to modify this button into rounded square button like in the following links below. i am not asking how to make the corners of a button round.
i want to get rounded square clickable background for each button with text on it.
is it good idea to create separate linear layout for each button?

check these examples 
https://www.flickr.com/photos/122631355@N06/13697400685 
https://www.flickr.com/photos/122631355@N06/13697229355

Comment: a `GridView` is not a `GridLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the layout like this and manage according to your exact reqirement..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="6" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_Dashboard"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/exam_logo" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HOME_SCREEN_FONT"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="DeshBoard" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_MyExam"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/exam_logo" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HOME_SCREEN_FONT"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="MyExam" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_AboutUs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/exam_logo" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HOME_SCREEN_FONT"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="About Us" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_ContactUs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/exam_logo" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HOME_SCREEN_FONT"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Contact Us" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_AboutUs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/exam_logo" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HOME_SCREEN_FONT"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="About Us" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_ContactUs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/exam_logo" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/HOME_SCREEN_FONT"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Contact Us" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```